# Regarding the .replace() Function

Tags: python-2.7, str-replace

I am fairly new to Python and am trying to create my own small program. Im having trouble with the replace function. I want to replace every even position in a string with its position number, and a problem occurs when the position becomes greater than 10; it just keeps replacing every character after 10 with an even number. Here is my code

```
def replaceEvenUntil(st,n):
    for i in range(len(st)):
        if i % 2 == float(0):
            st = st.replace(st[i], str(i), n)
    return st

>>> replaceEvenUntil("abcdefghijklmnop", 100)
'0b2d4f6h8j101214161820'
```

Where in my code have I made my error?

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. `float` and `str` are functions in Python. You don't need to write `int(0)` or `str('foo')`.
2. `str.replace('a', 'b')` replaces *all* occurrences of `a` with `b`. You don't really want that.
3. You're re-assigning `st` in the loop, but the size of `st` may change (`10` is two characters), so you'll get off-by-one errors as the strings grow larger than 10 characters long.

I would construct a temporary string instead:

```
def replaceEvenUntil(s, n):
    result = ''

    for i in range(min(n, len(s))):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result += str(i)
        else:
            result += s[i]

    return result
```

Or with `enumerate()`:

```
def replaceEvenUntil(s, n):
    result = ''

    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if i <= n and i % 2 == 0:
            result += str(i)
        else:
            result += s[i]

    return result
```

Comment: Thanks! It never came to me that I was changing the length of my string while i had it in the for loop.